# Sending HTML form data array to JSP/Servlet

Tags: html, arrays, forms, jsp, servlets

I am coming from the PHP world, where any form data that has a name ending in square brackets automatically gets interpreted as an array.  So for example:

```
<input type="text" name="car[0]" />
<input type="text" name="car[1]" />
<input type="text" name="car[3]" />
```

would be caught on the PHP side as an array of name "car" with 3 strings inside.

Now, is there any way to duplicate that behavior when submitting to a JSP/Servlet backend at all?  Any libraries that can do it for you?

EDIT:

To expand this problem a little further:

In PHP,

```
<input type="text" name="car[0][name]" />
<input type="text" name="car[0][make]" />
<input type="text" name="car[1][name]" />
```

would get me a nested array.  How can I reproduce this in JSP?

Comment: [JSP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JavaServer_Pages) comes to mind.

Comment: @Makoto That doesn't address the question, though; JSP doesn't do any type conversion of its own.

Comment: FYI Java is a word and not an acronym

Answer (score 11):

The `[]` notation in the request parameter name is a necessary hack in order to get PHP to recognize the request parameter as an array. This is **unnecessary** in other web languages like JSP/Servlet. Get rid of those brackets

```
<input type="text" name="car" />
<input type="text" name="car" />
<input type="text" name="car" />
```

This way they will be available by [`HttpServletRequest#getParameterValues()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String[] cars = request.getParameterValues("car");
// ...
```

#### See also:

- [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get/)

Comment: Interesting... and good to know.

Then this begs the next question:  Can you have 2 dimensional arrays in Java?  Like `car[0][make]`?

Comment: You'd need to collect them yourself in a loop. JSP/Servlet isn't that high-level as PHP. Better look for more sane ways or just a MVC framework like Spring MVC or JSF so that the model values are automagically updated.

Comment: I agree with the framework idea, but that fails in the case that you generate more form fields on the client side.  Here is the example I am struggling with:

Let's say you have a form that captures an event registration.  You get all your standard fields, but can add 0 to 10 guests to your registration.  In PHP you could have JS generate a guest[0][firstname] input field for the first guest and a guest[1][firstname] field for the second. Going with a Spring MVC, you would have to account for all 10 guests from the start and submit blank data for all of them.

Comment: Then use the framework-provided facilities to dynamically create components in server side. Or just collect them yourself in a loop, as said in previous comment.