# Accessing HTML-Input field arrays in Java Servlet / Structure of the input fields

Tags: java, html, servlets, input

I've got a dynamic number of fieldsets with 3 input fields each ordered differently, for example:

```
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" name="fieldset[1][valueA]">
  <input type="text" name="fieldset[1][valueB]">
  <input type="text" name="fieldset[1][valueC]">
</fieldset>
<fieldset>
  <input type="text" name="fieldset[2][valueC]">
  <input type="text" name="fieldset[2][valueB]">
  <input type="text" name="fieldset[2][valueA]">
</fieldset>
```

I would like to access these fields within a Java servlet in a loop, but I don't know how to adress these fields.

It would be possible with the input's name this way

```
fieldset[n][]
```

and a loop this way (to access the fields of fieldset[1]

```
String[] elements;
elements = request.getParameterValues("fieldset[1]");
for(int i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
out.write(elements[i]);
}
```

But is there any way I can do this and at the same time keep the information in the second bracket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems  The using [] notation  causing the  problem .

The  `HttpServletRequest.getParameterValues()`  can loop like in the below link.

check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786486/sending-html-form-data-array-to-jsp-servlet)