# Get Values from Multiple textbox

Tags: javascript, java, jsp

I have multiple textboxes, How to get value from it.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#btnAdd").bind("click", function () {
        var div = $("<div />");
        div.html(GetDynamicTextBox(""));
        $("#TextBoxContainer").append(div);
    });
    $("#btnGet").bind("click", function () {
        var values = "";
        $("input[name=a]").each(function () {
            values += $(this).val() + "\n";
        });
        alert(values);
    });
    $("body").on("click", ".remove", function () {
        $(this).closest("div").remove();
    });
});
function GetDynamicTextBox(value) {
    return '<input name = "a" type="text" value = "' + value + '" />&nbsp;' +
            '<input type="button" value="Remove" class="remove" />'
}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method='POST' action='AddReqPo'>
<input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="Add" />
<br />
<br />
<div id="TextBoxContainer">
    <!--Textboxes will be added here -->
</div>
<br />
<input id="btnGet" type="button" value="Get Values" />
<input type='submit'>
</form>
```

I want to save values to servlet. But when the button submit send values, there are errors **java.lang.NullPointerException**. This is the servlet file.

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    String[] a=request.getParameterValues("a");
        System.out.println(a[0]);
    response.sendRedirect("index.jsp");
}
```

Comment: @RayonDabre that's for php

Comment: @Ramanlfc, Yeah..you got it right..http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11786486/sending-html-form-data-array-to-jsp-servlet might help!

Comment: that's question there is not validate answer

Answer (score 0):

none of your `click` handlers will work when you submit the form(as you aren't preventing the default submit action with `preventDefault()`), so when your form submits , the statement in the servlet `String[] a=request.getParameterValues("a");` will set `a` to `null` and `System.out.println(a[0]);` this throws `NullPointerException`

Comment: can you help me for this issue?

Comment: @demahardika use `preventDefault()` in your handlers and take your div out of the form

Comment: @demahardika `function handler(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
}` read : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault

Comment: @demahardika try this with your handlers `$("#btnAdd").bind("click", function (e) {e.preventDefault(); ..rest of code`

Comment: I'am beginner and I'm so blind with js. I dont know where I must put your advice

Comment: @demahardika look at cde in my last comment and look at your js ,you'll get it

Comment: @demahardika all the `bind` methods have a function just pass argument `e` to them and call `e.preventDefault();` here's one example : https://jsfiddle.net/dkzftyqc/

Answer (score 0):

the code is working correctly. Servlet is not accessible.
 Try change please.

```
<form method='POST' action='AddReqPo'>
```

to

```
<form method='POST' action='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/AddReqPo'>
```