# How to send request parameter array to servlet using jQuery $.ajax?

Tags: jquery, arrays, ajax, servlets

I would like to send JavaScript array to servlet using jQuery `$.ajax`.

```
var json=[1,2,3,4];
$.ajax({
            url:"myUrl",
            type:"POST",
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(data){
                // codes....
            },
            data:json

        });
```

When I use

```
request.getParameter("json");
request.getParameterValues("json");
```

It returns null.

How can I access the values?

Comment: data is a JSON object so it must be like data: {name value pair, where value could be a object}

Comment: I don't see anywhere that you define a parameter named _json_ so I'm not sure why you'd expect _getParameter("json")_ to return anything other than null.

Comment: Are you trying to post to a server side file? to store the data in a database for example?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Send array as value of JS object so you end up as `{json:[1,2,3,4]}`.

```
var json=[1,2,3,4];
$.ajax({
    url:"myUrl",
    type:"POST",
    dataType:'json',
    data: {json:json},
    success:function(data){
        // codes....
    },
});
```

In servlet, you need to suffix the request parameter name with `[]`.

```
String[] myJsonData = request.getParameterValues("json[]");
```

jQuery appends them in order to be friendly towards [weak typed languages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get) like PHP.

Comment: Made a mistake on the server side you may have to use..
request.getParameterValues("json[]");

Answer (score 0):

You have to convert your array to a JSON type so instead of [] it needs to read

```
 var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ];
```

to do this you need to call

```
 var json = JSON.stringify(array)
```

then you can pass it into your ajax call

```
 $.ajax({ url:"myUrl",
          type:"POST",
          data: json,
          dataType:'json',
          success:function(data){
             // codes....
          }})
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using below script -

```
 jQuery.ajax({
                    url : "your API",
                    type : "POST",
                    dataType:'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify({ jsonData: data }),
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    success : function(response) {
    //do the needful.
    },
                    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus,
                            errorThrown) {
                        var x = 1;
                        closeLoader();  
                    }
                });
```

handle the request in the controller as below -

```
@RequestMapping(value="your url", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Map<String, Object> verifyRefundRequested(@RequestBody String data) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
        Map<String, Object> responseMap = null;
        Gson g = new Gson();
        responseMap = g.fromJson(data, Map.class);
        List<String> s = (List<String>) responseMap.get("jsonData");
//iterate list and process 
// return map
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to post your javascript data object like this..

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/

```
$.post("test.php", { name: "John", time: "2pm" },
   function(data) {
     alert("Data Loaded: " + data);
   });
```