# read javascript array from servlet

Tags: java, javascript, arrays, servlets

My question is

> how to read javascript array from servlet

Using javascript, I am reading the creating the `ArrayList` as follows:

```
var data1= new Array();
for(var i=1;i<=count;i++){
    var Obj=new Object();
    Obj.Name=$('#name'+i).val();
    Obj.url=$('#empno'+i).val();
    data1.push(""+Obj);
}
$.post("servlet", {'array':data1,mode:"insert" });
```

From servlet how to read the values

```
String[] data=request.getParameterValues("array[]");
```

Comment: Have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13241668/how-to-send-array-to-servlet-using-jquery-ajax

Comment: From servlet with the following code i reading the arraylist

    String[] data=request.getParameterValues("array[]");
    Sytem.out.println("------"data[0]);
   it is printing [object object]

Pls suggest how to get the  name and url in the array

Answer (score 0):

You can get parameters from the request

```
String array = request.getParameter("array");
String mode= request.getParameter("mode");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Json.stringify".

```
$.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost:8080/JasonToServlet/test',
        type: 'POST', 
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {"json[]": JSON.stringify(data1)},
        success: function(result) {
        }
   });
```

This will parse the array as string as follows:

```
 [{"Name":"Test","url":"Me"},{"Name":"Test2","url":"Me2"}]
```

The problem here is that above result is a string not an array. So you gonna have to use stringtokenizer to split the string and make it as array.

From servlet get this as:

```
String row= request.getParameter("json[]");
String row1= request.getParameter("mode");
StringTokenizer str = new StringTokenizer(row, "[{}]");
List<String> temp = new ArrayList<String>();

while (str.hasMoreElements()) {
    String token = str.nextToken(); 
    if(!token.equal(","))
        temp.add(token);
}
```

**THIS IS NOT A PERFECT SOLUTION, BUT IT WORKS.. :)**