# Pass 2D ArrayList to Servlet?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, arraylist

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
     <style>
        .col-lg-10{
            background-color: #ffffcc;
            margin: 10px;
        }
    </style>
   <script>
       var array1=new Array()();
       document.getElementById("sales_Details").value=array1;

        function add(){
           var reference=document.getElementById('sales_ref_No').value;
           var product=document.getElementById('product_ID');
           var productID=product.options[product.selectedIndex].text;
           var productPrice=document.getElementById('product_ID').value;
           var description=document.getElementById('sales_Description').value;
           var unit=document.getElementById('sales_Unit').value;
           var total=Number(document.getElementById('sales_Total').value);
           var price= parseFloat(productPrice*unit);
           total+=price;

           var table=document.getElementsByTagName('table')[0];

           var newRow=table.insertRow(1);

           var cell1=newRow.insertCell(0);
           var cell2=newRow.insertCell(1);
           var cell3=newRow.insertCell(2);
           var cell4=newRow.insertCell(3);

           cell1.innerHTML=productID;
           cell2.innerHTML=description;
           cell3.innerHTML=unit;  
           cell4.innerHTML=price;

           document.getElementById('sales_Total').value=total;

           array1.push([reference,productID,description,unit,price]);
       }

   </script>
</head>
<body>
    <jsp:include page="navigationBar.jsp"></jsp:include>
    <div class="container">
        <%=login_Location_ID%>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>
        <div class="col-lg-10">
            <form class="form-horizontal" action="SalesController" method="POST">
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Fill in the information</legend>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Sales Reference No</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sales_ref_No" name="sales_ref_No" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Create By</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="user_ID" name="user_ID" required/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Product</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <select class="form-control" id="product_ID" name="product_ID">
                                <c:forEach var="product" items="${product}">
                                    <option value="<c:out value="${product.product_Price}"/>"><c:out value="${product.product_ID}"/></option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Description</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-8">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sales_Description" name="sales_Description"/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Unit</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="number" class="form-control" id="sales_Unit" name="sales_Unit" required/>
                        </div>
                        <button type="button" onclick="add();">Add</button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">Total</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="sales_Total" name="sales_Total" readonly/>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-sm-2">location</label>
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <select class="form-control" name="location_ID">
                                <c:forEach var="location" items="${location}">
                                    <option value="<c:out value="${location.location_ID}"/>"><c:out value="${location.location_ID}"/></option>
                                </c:forEach>
                            </select>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <%
                        if(request.getAttribute("insertError")!=null){
                    %>
                    <p style="text-align: center; background-color: transparent;color:red"><c:out value="${insertError}"/> is Existed</p>
                    <%
                        }
                    %>
                    <table border="3">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Product ID</th>
                            <th>Description</th>
                            <th>Unit</th>
                            <th>Price</th>
                        </tr>
                    </table> 
                    <input type="hidden" id="sales_Details" name="sales_Details"/>
                    <input type="hidden" name="action" value="insertSales"/>
                    <div class="form-group">        
                        <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
                            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-default">Clear</button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-lg-1"></div>            
    </div>
    <div class="container"><jsp:include page="footer.jsp"></jsp:include></div>  
</body>
```

Hello, I'm newbie in JSP and I want to ask something.

I have an order table in the form which user can add multiple items and submit... the order data are stored inside `array1` which shown in the picture.

My problem now is that I don't have any idea on what syntax should I use to pass the `ArrayList` to the servlet.

I tried using `input type=hidden name="array1" id="array1" value=array1"` but it does not seem to work.

Comment: Welcome to SO, please post your code in textform.

Comment: Might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26976639/sending-a-2d-array-jquery-post-to-java-servlet

Comment: If you are trying to pass a complex object to the server, use a POST method.

Comment: i try with JSON.stringify(array1)
and then the result come out with this error
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Answer (score 0):

You can use JSON format for your data. [Google: "*json*"](https://www.google.com/search?q=json).

The idea is to convert your data into JSON and pass it as a text (String), and then parse it (you can use [Gson](https://github.com/google/gson/blob/master/UserGuide.md) or [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson/wiki)).

JSON example:
https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp

1-D array

```
[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
```

2-D array of numbers

```
[
    ["2009-01", 324, 1075, 940, 441, 1040, 898, 1343],
    ["2009-02", 295, 958, 904, 434, 1038, 793, 1246 ]
]
```

Here, you can see how to convert data from the form into JSON. Then pass String 
`dataFromForm` to the server and parse it.
[Serialize form data to JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11338774/serialize-form-data-to-json)