# How to write a http get request when a key's value is an array?

Tags: java, arrays, servlets

I have written a java servlet to deal with http get request.I know ,the common format of get request is like this:`http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/test?name="jack"&value="shit`.

But now ,I have a list of values to transfer,such as an user id `list[1,2,3,4]`.So ,my question is ,how should I write my http get request to express this?And in java servets `doGet()`,can I use `request.getParameterValues` to get such an array?

Comment: Depending on what the list represents, it'd likely be better as JSON or XML in the body of the request.

Comment: The name of the field in the HTML form can be changed from `myfield` to `myfield[]` in order to make arrays possible.

Comment: You mean "http://ip:8080/test?name="jack"&value[]=[1,2,3,4]" ?@AlexvanOostenrijk

Comment: @Makoto if the request body is JSON or XML ,then the request type should be changed to post instead of get,right?

Answer (score 3):

if you are using GET method your url should be looking like that :

```
 http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/test?list=1&list=2&list=3
```

for retrieving it:

```
String[] arrlist=request.getParameterValues('list');
```

your array will be filled with separated values:

```
//["1","2","3"]
```

**UPDATE : if to write it list[] or list?**

when you retrieving your list parameters it wouldn't be parsed as array but as a **series of String**  which will be grouped later on into an array.
Which means even if you write it `list[]=1&list[]=2&list[]=3`, `list[=1&list[=2&list[=3`, `list*=1&list*=2&list*=3` or `list=1&list=2&list=3` it would always be giving you the same answer whether you retrieve it as

```
request.getParameterValues('list[]') //["1","2","3"]
request.getParameterValues('list[') //["1","2","3"]
request.getParameterValues('list*') //["1","2","3"]
request.getParameterValues('list')  //["1","2","3"]
```

Answer (score 0):

While ,the http request format should be like this:localhost:8080/test?list[]=1&list[]=2&list[]=3

Comment: you cannot do that ! unless you want your variable to be named as "list[]" look at my answer above

Comment: look at this page:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get

Comment: exactly like i have told you when you will be retrieving  your list[] parameters it wouldn't be parsed as array but as a serie of String parameter which will be grouped later on into an array which mean even if you write it list[]=1&list[]=2&list[]=3 or list[=1&list[=2&list[=3 or list*=1&list*=2&list*=3 it would always give you the same answer if you retrieve it like that request.getParameterValues('list[]') request.getParameterValues('list[') request.getParameterValues('list*')

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too simple, but what about repeat parameters name?

```
http://IP_ADDRESS:8080/test?userId=1&userId=2&userId=3
```