# REST API: multiple resources in one GET

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, rest, ruby-on-rails-4

I need to fetch several ids in one GET request like

```
http://localhost:3000/api/positions/ids
```

I've tried some ways to do this, but no one worked:

This returned only first object:

```
http://localhost:3000/api/positions/1,2
```

this

`http://localhost:3000/api/positions?id=1,2`

and that

`http://localhost:3000/api/positions?id=1&id=2`

returned all objects, but first and second.

How can I do it? Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get

this seems to answer your problem, the second answer

Comment: Are you creating an API or using an API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax for arrays in parameters is `id[]=1&id[]=2&id[]=3` but if you have large numbers of ids then this can become quite cumbersome and ugly.  I would suggest that you use the parameter `id` for a single id and a separate parameter `ids` which takes a hyphen-seperated single string, eg

```
#get a single resource
/api/positions?id=123

#get a list of resources
/api/positions?ids=123-67-456-1-3-5
```

Now you can make your controller code something like this:

```
if params[:id]
  @foos = Foo.find_all_by_id(params[:id])
elsif params[:ids]
  @foos = Foo.find_all_by_id(params[:ids].split("-"))
end
```

Comment: @Max In your code "@foos = Foo.find_all_by_id(params[:ids].split("-"))" the 'Foo' is some database service i guess. Am i correct? Also its upto the 'find_all_by_id' function implementation that it should return the list of resources

Comment: Yes, "Foo.find_all_by_id" refers to Rails' implementation of the ActiveRecord pattern, and is equivalent to `"select * from foos where id in (123,456,789)"`.  It will return an array of Foo objects, the ones matching the ids in the string.