# Java Servlet - get parameters with same name

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, servlets, post

I know that I can get a parameter like:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="field" value="test">
```

**Servlet**

```
String field = request.getParameter("field");
```

But what if I have multiple input with same name like:

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" name="line[]" value="test1">
<input type="text" name="line[]" value="test2">
<input type="text" name="line[]" value="test3">
```

In PHP I can just use `name="line[]"` to get an array of all the line inputs. But how to go about this in java?

**Servlet pseudo code**

```
String[] lines = request.getParameterArray("line");

for(String line : lines){
    //do shit
}
```

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletRequest.html#getParameterValues%28java.lang.String%29

Comment: Here's some background information why weak typed languages like PHP use the awkward `[]` suffix convention: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3061292

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Close. It's

```
String[] lines = request.getParameterValues("line");
```

but the name is `line`, not `line[]`