# How can I read from servlet form inputs with name="product[]"

Tags: jsp

I have a form where the input's name are :

```
<form>
<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="col-md-1">                                      
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="product[]"/>        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="col-md-1">                                      
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="product[]"/>        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]"/>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="form-group" >
    <div class="col-md-1">                                      
        <input type="text"  class="form-control"  name="product[]"/>        
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="description[]"/>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

I am wondering if I can read these values from my servlet.. Is there a way to iterate through all the inputs `product[]` and `description[]`?

I tried `String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description[]");` and

```
while(!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getParameter("description[]"))){
   String description = request.getParameter("description[]");
   System.out.println("desct = " + description);
}
```

but it didn't read the values..

Comment: The form has an add button so it creates similar inputs.. I was wondering if this works before I try to edit the add button function.

Comment: Because the name of the parameter isn't `description`, but `description[]`. I.e. you have to use `String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description[]");`.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek It doesn't work..

Comment: is that an array of inputs in an element of HTML ?

Comment: @yaylitzis Just tested it locally, and works for me nicely. Are you sure you are calling the servlet? I don't see any `action` attribute in your form.

Comment: @JozefChocholacek Actually I had left the attribute `disabled` in the input that's why I didn't get the values..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After @JozefChocholacek comment I found where the problem was. There was the attribute `disabled` in the input form. I deleted and then the

```
while(!StringUtils.isBlank(request.getParameter("description[]"))){
   String description = request.getParameter("description[]");
   System.out.println("desct = " + description);
}
```

worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

[Java Servlet - get parameters with same name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30849694/java-servlet-get-parameters-with-same-name)

So `String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description");` might work!? Without the `[]` in the name.

Answer (score -1):

As you have written `name="description [ ]"` so you should get the value/values by this name only.

So your statement should be:

```
String[] description = request.getParameterValues("description[ ]");
```

Comment: Please consider about formatting the answer while you post.