# How to let Spring MVC decode multi-valued request parameters with incorrect [] suffix?

Tags: arrays, spring, servlet-filters, http-request-parameters

When

```
jQuery.ajax({ ... 
     data: { 
           search: {input : 'value'} 
           array : [1,2]

     }
}
```

The method will request the url:

```
url?search[input]=value&array[]=1&array[]=2
```

which follows the **application/x-www-form-urlencoded** format from what I understand.

But the Spring application, can not turn this into a HashMap for search or array[] on key array on the server side.

Instead this is what we get,

[image]

Is there a way to add filter in Spring to participate in the creation of the request.getParameterMap() ?

Are there any such filters already written and available as opensource?

Any other thoughts?

Comment: FYI: this is definitely not "conform application/x-www-form-urlencoded format". It's conform "PHP format". See also a.o. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get

Comment: @BalusC The thing is that jQuery seems to prefer this format, and I would like the option of getting access to hashmap like properties. Of course I could build it myself, but server side is already parsing the query once.

Comment: I am mostly interested in the hashmap functionality, as getting the array already works.