# Passing array from Android to _GET php

Tags: php, android, arrays

How to pass below array from Andriod?
I want to pass this array to PHP.

```
b_array=[ [1,y],[3,y],[4,n],[5,n],[99,y],[1001,y],[1002,n],[1003,y],…]
```

How to received array (`GET` / `POST` ) in PHP. My Database structure required data in two part

```
part 1 ( id )> 1
part 2 ( status )> y
```

b_array will be one variable pass from android and b_array length cant be fix.
b_array length depends on user input.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get)

Comment: here i want to pass array in one variable

Comment: You know they are two distinct systems, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, use `okhttp` to send GET request.
Second, make `b_array` to json, xml or etc which can represent array.
Third, parse those request at PHP-side.