# how can I submit several different values with a same name through jquery $.post

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, servlets

I'm attempting to submit several parameters using Jquery post method, here is how I wrote the code.
Jquery:

```js
$(document).on("input",".li-add input", function() {
     var input = $("#add-purposes").val();
     if(input != "") {
      $("#outter-d-1").load("/UniHealths/UNCManageDataDictionaryServlet?type=search #d-1", {
       queryString:input,
       resultUrl:"/dictionary/treatment",
       resultSetName:"dictionary_conditions",
       queryType:["CONDITION","SYMPTOM"]
      });
     } else {
      $("#d-1").empty();
     }
    })
```

I use ***queryType*** as the parameter name, and it has two values in the array, when I use HttpServletRequest's method getParameter("queryType") from server, I got a null pointer, why this happens? how can i submit two different values with a same name?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3061273

Answer (score 1):

> As of jQuery 1.4, the `$.param()` method serializes deep objects
>   recursively to accommodate modern scripting languages and frameworks
>   such as PHP and Ruby on Rails. You can disable this functionality
>   globally by setting `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;`

This also means, that arrays will be serialized as `paramName[]` (note the `[]` at the end).

So in your case the server receive param with name: `queryType[]`, not `queryType`.

To alter this jQuery behaviour you can set the
`jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional = true;` before sending the request.

But beware:

> As of jQuery 3.0, the `$.param()` method no longer uses
>   `jQuery.ajaxSettings.traditional` as its default setting and will
>   default to `false`.

So if you use jQuery 3.x, you shoud explicitly set the `traditional` option in the `settings` of your request.

As far as I know, the `.load()` function doesn't support `settings` parameter, so use [`.ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) instead.

The `settings` parameter should include `traditional: true` if you want to serialize arrays without adding `[]` to param name.