# How to pass an array within a query string in http GET method?

Tags: javascript, java, node.js, web-services

How to pass the array values in Query String using http GET method?

http://localhost:3011/api/latest/os/archive/catalogue?Labels=[{Label: Name of Label-1},{Label: Name of Label-2}]&CatalogueID=101&ArchivePolicyID=122

if, passing these values, how to get array values, using key or index values.

Comment: I believe this should help you.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Possible duplicate of: [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get)

Answer (score 0):

You can create an array in a url using array assignment eg. `things[]=zero&things[]=one` which will look like `things = ["zero", "one"]` on the server.

You also need to assign an associative array with `things[][label]=value` which will be picked up on the server as `things = [{label: "value"}]`

```
http://localhost:3011/api/latest/os/archive/catalogue?Labels[][label]=Name%20of%20Label-1&Labels[][label]=Name%20of%20Label-2}]&CatalogueID=101&ArchivePolicyID=122
```