# how can I return Array From Postman Array Like [1,2,3]?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach, postman

I'm Working on rest API. I need To Pass Array Like [1,2,3]

[image]

That Course Return in `$request->course`

After I Run For each Loop That is Show

```
foreach ($request->course as $key => $value) {
                 echo $value;die;
                }
```

its Show `Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

Thank You

Answer (score 0):

By passing [1,2,3] in `course` your as sending a string.

You should look at [Send an Array with an HTTP Get](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3061273/send-an-array-with-an-http-get) to find a solution.

To answer to your question, you should send 3 parameters :

```
course[]=1
course[]=2
course[]=3
```